# Analytic functions in a punctured disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous in the open disk $\{z:|z|<1\}$. If $f$ is analytic in $\{z:0<|z|<1\}$, ie: analytic in the punctured unit disk, then $f$ is analytic $\{z:|z|<1\}$.

How does one relate the continuity of the function to the analyticness of the function at the removed point?

Comment: I guess the Cauchy integral formula is not allowed?

Comment: HINT: Use Morera's Theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isolated singularities of analytic functions are of three types:

1. Removable singularities.
2. Poles.
3. Essential singularities.

In cases 2 and 3 the function is not bounded in any punctured neighbourhood of the singularity. Since $f$ is continuous, the only possible case is 1.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!