# What would this punctured disc look like?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Say I have a punctured disc D'(0;1). How would I draw this? I'm kind of confused as to what a punctured disc actually is at the moment.

Comment: I think it is without just the center point. But it was some years ago I read the definition.

Comment: It seems to be what they use in this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320016/analytic-functions-in-a-punctured-disk $0<|z|<1$ note the strict inequality for $0$.

Comment: To draw it:  Draw a large circle (radius $1$) to indicate the unit disk.  Then a draw a small circle at the center, to indicate that the center point is missing.

Comment: I also found a hat for ya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)

Comment: @mathreadler not sure why you're calling me stupid when you was unable to actually answer the question yourself? Was your comment meant for a different post?

Comment: @isawahatonce It was just intended as a friendly reference to your supposed interest in hats as implied by your username.